# Select only part of a string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query:

```
Select
    Notes
From
    Table
```

And a sample out put may be:

```
78652972MWGN00183HCE736430
77305311FTBCHCE735946Wheat
Training
```

However is what I would like as the output is an ID within the string, the ID always starts with `HCE` and is always 8 characters long, and where the is no ID, it would return `No Machine ID`

So my desired out put for the above would be:

```
HCE736430
HCE735946
No Machine Id
```

How can I achieve this ?

I have looked at using `SUBSTRING`, but cannot search for the HCE part.

I am currently doing this in Excel using `MID` and `SEARCH`:

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("HCE",A2),9)
```

Comment: Look at CHARINDEX.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5):

You can use PATINDEX for this. Here is an example.

```
declare @Something table (SomeVal varchar(50))

insert @Something values
('78652972MWGN00183HCE736430')
, ('77305311FTBCHCE735946Wheat')
, ('Training')
,('asdfHCExx')



select case when patindex('%HCE[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]%', SomeVal) > 0
    then substring(SomeVal, patindex('%HCE[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]%', SomeVal), 9)
    else 'No Machine Id'
end

from @Something
```

Comment: I updated this to handle a length of 8 characters. Not very clear what the OP expects for valid characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `patindex()` with `substring()` :

```
SELECT Notes, SUBSTRING(Notes, PATINDEX('%HCE%', Notes +'HCE'), 9)
From Table;
```

First version will display `blank` if the `Machine Id` note found if you want to display `No Machine Id` instead then you can add `case` expression :

```
(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%HCE%', Notes) > 0
      THEN SUBSTRING(Notes, PATINDEX('%HCE%', Notes), 9)
      ELSE 
      'No Machine Id'
 END)
```

Comment: This may return false positives if they have HCE in the string not followed by 6 digits.

Comment: @SeanLange. . .  I have a read this `the ID always starts with HCE and is always 8 characters long,`

Comment: Maybe it is just characters and I interpreted it as digits. But This could still return false positives if HCE falls towards then end. Not saying this is wrong, just saying it may return false positives. :)

Answer (score 2):

This query does what you are asking for:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('HCE', Notes) = 0 THEN 'No MachineID' ELSE 
SUBSTRING(Gender, CHARINDEX('HCE', Notes), 9) END
FROM  Table
```

Comment: This may return false positives if they have HCE in the string not followed by 6 digits.

Comment: That was not part of the specification, actually.

Comment: "the ID always starts with HCE and is always 8 characters long". This isn't necessarily incorrect, just saying it could possibly return false positives.